# Jupyter notebook URL's token gets truncated in Docker image on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, command-line, jupyter-notebook

I created a Docker image from an Anaconda environment and all went well. However, when I run the image, the part with the token in the notebook URL is truncated so I can't visit the link. It instead prompts me to create a password (on the web page) which also needs the token.

This is the output I am getting even in full screen command line mode.

I'm running:

```
docker run crypto_forecaster
```

and getting:

```
[I 23:23:47.302 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 23:23:47.732 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /usr/src/app
[I 23:23:47.732 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 23:23:47.732 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 23:23:47.732 NotebookApp] http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=...
[I 23:23:47.732 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Comment: You can define your own token with something like `docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password='sha1:74ba40f8a388:c913541b7ee99d15d5ed31d4226bf7838f83a50e'`. See: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook/

Answer (score 0):

First you can generate a hashed password using the below python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from getpass import getpass
from hashlib import sha1

password = 'your-password'
m = sha1(password.encode('utf-8'))
print("SHA1: " + m.hexdigest())
```

Then add to your docker run command as eMMe above. If you're using docker compose add it to the command property:

```
   ...
   image: jupyter/scipy-notebook
   command: "start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password=$*your-sha1-password-above*"
   ports:
      - "8888:8888"
   ...
```